# Logging Only Properties of Object That Have Changed in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm messing around with objects and making changes and doing testing within the code. I've found that it's quite tedious to log an object, view it in the console, and then open it up and find which parts I'm testing for changes.

Is there a way to log only parts of the object that has changed?

For example when you click a button with the ID of saveSettings:

```
$("#saveSettings").click(function () {
    console.log(settings);
});
```

It will of course log the full object called "settings".

To give you an idea, my object looks like this at the moment (but much more):

```
var settings= {
    social: {
        username: "JSmith"
    },
    general: {
        color: "red"
    }
};
```